# Getting today's name in a list and add next 5 days in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list. It must have 5 days in a row. I got today's name and added in first list item. I need to add next 4 days for other elements. i guess i need a kind of loops but i am new on JS and i didnt find a way. waiting for helps.

```js
(function() {
  var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

  Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    return daysOfWeek[this.getDay()];
  };
})();

var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDayName();

$('li:first').html(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul>
      <li></li> <!-- Today -->
      <li></li> <!-- tomorrow -->
      <li></li> <!-- day after tomorrow -->
      <li></li> <!-- and other -->
      <li></li> <!-- and other -->
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: It's usually considered bad practice to extend the native JS prototypes. See [this question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/104320/23729) for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to the following code snippet

```js
(function() {
  var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

  Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
    return daysOfWeek[this.getDay()];
  };
  var now = new Date();
  var day = now.getDayName();

  $('li:first').html(day);
  var currentDayNumber = daysOfWeek.indexOf(day);
  currentDayNumber = (currentDayNumber + 1) % 7;
  $("li:not(:first)").each(function(li) {
    $(this).html(daysOfWeek[currentDayNumber]);
    currentDayNumber = (currentDayNumber + 1) % 7;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <!-- Today -->
    <li></li>
    <!-- tomorrow -->
    <li></li>
    <!-- day after tomorrow -->
    <li></li>
    <!-- and other -->
    <li></li>
    <!-- and other -->
  </ul>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

```js
var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

var now = new Date();
var dayIdx = now.getDay();

$('li').each(function(idx, el){
  $(el).html(daysOfWeek[(dayIdx+idx)%7]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul>
      <li></li> <!-- Today -->
      <li></li> <!-- tomorrow -->
      <li></li> <!-- day after tomorrow -->
      <li></li> <!-- and other -->
      <li></li> <!-- and other -->
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a clean solution.  I like how short you made it...  I wasn't thinking of using the each return object.  Great solution...

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

   (function() {
      Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
        return daysOfWeek[this.getDay()];
      };
    })()

var now = new Date();
var tday = now.getDayName();
var d = daysOfWeek.indexOf(tday);
$.each(daysOfWeek, function(){
    if(d == 7){
       d=0;
    }
    var day = daysOfWeek[d];
    d++;
    $('body ul').append("<li>"+day+"</li>");
});
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L1e5rhok/